# making a new audio file without data conversion but of shorter length

Tags: java, audio, javasound

Snippet that gets the wanted length from the total length :

```
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( new File( "file.wav") );
clip.open( ais );
long currentPos = clip.getMicrosecondPosition(); // get the current position of clip
```

After these steps, is there a way that i can make up a new `audio file`, without data conversion *(keeping audio data same)* but it's length equal to the `currentPos` ?

*i.e cutting up the audio file and reducing it's size to `currentPos`*

Answer (score 1):

Clips aren't the most useful for manipulating audio data. I think you have to load your sound file into a byte array and work off of that.

To hear it, you can wrap the raw audio array in a TargetDataLine implementation. The TDL implementation gives you hooks to start or stop where-ever you like.

If you want to save the sliced files, you probably know about using AudioSystem.write() method which takes an AudioInputStream as one of the arguments. The TDL can be wrapped in an AIS for these writes.

If there is an easier way to do it, I'm looking forward to reading about it!

Answer (score -1):

lots of audio editing tools can do this sort of thing.  Try goldwave.